# Time Complexity of keySet() for encapsulated Map<> values

Tags: java, dictionary, set, time-complexity

I need a `HashMap` with the signature

```
HashMap<Integer, Double> map;
```

But I encapsulated two values like:

```
class CustomKV
{
    Integer key;
    Double value;
}
```

Hence, the `Map<>` becomes

```
Set<CustomKV> customMap;
```

If I were to use `Map`, when I wanted to iterate on the keys, `map.keySet()` would be sufficient.
However, if I use the second, I have to iterate on the objects of `CustomKV` and then add all the `key`s, add them in a set, then return it.

My question is: does Java have an optimization for this? Or each time I call `keySet()`, is it going to iterate on the objects?

### Edit:

Here, I write the difference of two iterations:

```
for(Integer i : map.keySet())

for(CustomKV kv : customMap())
```

it seems they are identical. But what I ask is, if I keep calling

```
for(CustomKV kv : customMap)
    int key = kv.getKey();
```

Would it slow me down, or does Java recognize this and treat `customMap` as a map?

Comment: Which valueS do you want to access? And what is the reason for using your CustomKV class instead of a Map?

Comment: What would you invoke `keySet()` on if you're using your custom `Set`?

Comment: @shmosel I will write a custom `keySet()` method as well.

Comment: @MKorsch I am using it to model the adjacency list of a vertex in a graph.

Comment: Why would iterating over `Set<CustomKV>` be any more or less efficient than iterating over `Set<Integer>`?

Comment: @shmosel I'm using `getKey()` each time. But `keySet()` provides all keys at once.

Comment: There's no significant overhead in calling a getter. And the `keySet` returned by `HashMap` is doing the same thing internally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're asking about Java's implementation, `HashMap` does cache the set after the first call to `keySet()`. But even the first call doesn't require any iteration, because it only returns a view, or wrapper, of the underlying entry set.

So, yes, Java does optimize their implementation, but technically you could apply the same optimizations to your custom set.

Answer (score 2):

`keySet()` does not create a new `Set`.

It simply offers a view of the keys in your map. It actually provides only a few operations which are iteration (with remove), size, emptiness, clear and contains. You cannot add an element to it otherwise it will throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Answer (score 0):

If there are more than 2 fields we should go for class ,like in your ex. `Set<CustomKV> customMap;`

and if only two values are there better to use Hashmap.

In both cases we can iterate.

But in case of Hashmap we can access `value` by `get` method using `key` and we can avoid iteration.